# Expanding text inside fixed-position divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having problems at the moment with expanding and collapsing sections using JQuery; the fixed position div won't let me change what's viewed in certain browsers.

It seemed to work fine previously when I didn't have the mainBlock and titleBlock divs, and if I remove the fixed position line the problem goes away, but then my divs aren't laid out how I'd like them to be.

As I said previously this is only a problem in some browsers: it seems to work fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome or IE.  I'm unsure What I'd need to change for each browser to make it work (also seems to work fine in [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LADransfield/emp2xwzk/1/))

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $(".collapse").click(function () {
        $(this).next().toggle();
        $(this).find('span').toggleClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-s");
    }).next().hide();

});
```

CSS:

```
.collapse span {
    display:inline-block;
    }
#titleBlock {
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    top:10px;
    height: 90px;
    z-index: 0;
}
#mainBlock {
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    top:110px;
    bottom: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="titleBlock">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Author <span style="float:right;">DD/MM/YYYY</span></h2>
</div>

<div id="mainBlock">

<h2 id="S1">Section 1</h2>
<p>Non-hidden text</p>

<h2 id="S1_1" class="collapse"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>Section 1.1</h2>
<p>Hidden Text </p>

</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean with "won't let me change"? Nothing happens when you click?

Comment: you must have some other scripts breaking it as if it works in the fiddle then something else must be wrong.  Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: Nothing happens when I click, and none of the :hover stuff works from the CSS either.
I can't see why it would work in the fiddle and in Firefox but not in Chrome or IE if it was something in the script blocking it? As far as I can tell there are no errors.

Comment: In chrome, press f12 and then click on the console tab - it will give you detail about if there is any errors or not.  If the code from your webpage is not exactly the same as the code in the fiddle, there could be other js that conflicts with the different browsers causing it not to work.  Each browser has nuances that cause certain bits of js or css to behave differently and they also handle errors differently so one browser may be able to skip over an error whereas another browser may break

Comment: I have also just noticed in your fiddle, you are including both jquery min and jquery.1.10.2 files - you only need to include either one or the other - not both.  The min version is just the same file with all extra spaces taken out to reduce the file size

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the z-index was causing the problems.

```
#titleBlock {
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    top:10px;
    height: 90px;
    z-index: 0;
}
#mainBlock {
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    top:110px;
    bottom: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Because the mainBlock was int he background I couldn't cliok it.